# Linux Python multiple command-line beeps

Tags: python, linux

I want my script to output audible beeps in response to certain events (EG- A happens, beep once; B happens, beep twice; C happens, beeps 3 times; etc.).  No matter how I write the code the script only beeps once.

I've tried:

```
print('\a\a\a') #only beeps once

print('\a')
print('\a') #only beeps once

os.system('\a\a\a') #only beeps once

os.system('\a')
os.system('\a') #only beeps once
```

Note: I had been successfully using aplay and .wav files to generate the beeps but I want to run this script on PythonAnywhere and aplay is not an option.

Comment: Try putting a small delay between beeps.

Comment: What's the output of `xset q | grep -i bell`? You may need to sleep for a few tenths of a second if you want a gap between the beeps.

Comment: Adding a pause with "time.sleep(.4)" did the trick. Thanks for the help.